# How to play youtube videos on windows application C#

Tags: c#, winforms, stream, youtube, webbrowser-control

I've created a windows application with a WebBrowser control and trying to play youtube videos.. I've installed Adobe Shockwave Player, and tried to watch video on my windows application, but it doesn't show any videos. When I hit play button the screen looks like this
[image]

My code for playing video is

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("utube.html");
        string PlayString = currentVideoUrl.Trim().Replace("watch?v=", "v/");
        string Finalplaycode = "<embed src=" + PlayString + "&hl=en&fs=1& type=application/x-shockwave-flash allowscriptaccess=always allowfullscreen=true width=425 height=344></embed>";
        sw.Write(Finalplaycode);
        sw.Close();
        string PathToNavigate = Directory.GetParent(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\utube.html";
        webBrowser1.Navigate(PathToNavigate);
```

and my example video link is : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZdnezj9Dfg&feature=BFa&list=PLD3E900BFF6534896&lf=plpp_video

can anyone help me about this issue? Did I missing any plug-in or something? I am using .NetFramework 4.0

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit application or a 64-bit application? Does the embed work if you try to navigate to it using Google Chrome or Internet Explorer?

Comment: I am using 32-bit application. What do you mean by saying navigate? You mean clicking a link in windows application and opening new browser with sent URL and play video? If yes, I can do that I know. But I am trying to play videos on my Windows Application. I found this article, but cannot find that FlashObjects.. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/5815e676-50b0-47f4-964a-c1bcebfdb9a4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I see is that you're not quoting the parameters in the embed. Your embed will generate as:

```
<embed src=http://www.youtube.com/v/video_id...>
```

You need to quote those parameters:

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/video_id...">
```

For example, here's an embed that works on my site:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/UejelYnVI3U&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1"></embed>
```

You might be interested in reading the official YouTube documentation. They've moved away from using embeds, in favor of iframes. That lets them use the HTML5 video player if it's available, or otherwise fall back to Flash. See http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=171780 for details.

Update:

The HTML file below embeds the same video in two ways: once using the iframe and once using the standard embed. It works find when I navigate to it with the `WebBrowser` control:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385"
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oZdnezj9Dfg" frameborder="0">
</iframe>

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="425" height="344"
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
<param name="src" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/oZdnezj9Dfg&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1" />
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="344" 
  src="http://www.youtube.com/v/oZdnezj9Dfg&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1">
</embed>
</object>

</body>
<html>
```

Try copying that and navigating to it in your application. Make sure that your program is creating the embed just like that.

Also, you can remove the outer `<object>` tag if you already have Flash installed. Then, the Flash embed looks just like what I showed originally.

And, there's no requirement that you have the HTML wrapper around it. It works fine if I just include the embed without the `<html>` and other tags.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem is in my windows application, your embed is not working. I've tried to embed youtube's original embed which using iFrame and HTML5 support, it is failed on my WebBroswer control too. So how can I enable flash player on my windows application?

Comment: or can you suggest me another way?

Comment: When I put your code my application tries to install Adobe Flash Player.. The problem is after downloadin 8Mb of data it says An error has occured while downloading the installer :(( I think we are on correct way, but flash player cannot be installing :(

Comment: @Serkan: I would suggest that you start Internet Explorer and install Flash player. It'll be easier to see why it's failing. After you get Flash installed, it should work.

Comment: I've already installed Adobe Flash Player 11 Plugin 64-bit and Adobe Shockwave Flash Player 11.6 :( Can I have your Gtalk or Skype to discuss problem?

Comment: Ok. It is working.. The problem is in my computer sir :( I tried it in another computer, and it worked fine..