# Play video on YouTube in WebBrowser with help script

Tags: c#, youtube, browser, playback

i need help...
I need to play the video (YouTube) in the component WebBrowser (C#) with a script. I found a script that runs playback :

```
 yt.player.playerReferences_.player1.api.playVideo()
```

But this script does not run video in WebBrowser component. The code:

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];  
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");  
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;  
element.text = "function playV() { yt.player.playerReferences_.player1.api.playVideo(); }";  
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);  
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("playV()");
```

Please help me. Maybe there's another way?

Comment: Check this link please

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083247/how-to-play-youtube-videos-on-windows-application-c-sharp

Comment: This is not what I need. I'm using the component WebBrowser. What command must I use (maybe YouTube API) to run the video in this component?